# Is there sense to separate one table to many

Tags: performance, mongodb

This is performance question.
Is split data to many data tables give you performance advantage  upon just using single data table indexed by property, on the base of which data could be separated to many data tables?

Thanks.

Comment: )) and where I could see or read about it, or it just should be investigated on the field?

Answer (score 0):

For one you gotta recognise that MongoDB has a collection limit that is dependant upon such things as index size: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections

Collections can be queried concurrently however Mongo has a global (db level in 2.2) lock so for performance reasons in terms of writes it would seem more feasible to split your data into DBs if you were dealing with MANY writes per sec to one node.

The main benefit to using multiple collections is the scalability. It is easier to shard many collections than one gigantic collection and it also easier to use a shard key that will always make querying relatively fast. It is also easier for extent reasons. Big docs = more moving of docs across HDD space when they grow.

The main benefit to using one collection is ease of querying. But you gotta remember embedding document 3 levels or more deep might not be a good option and it does make querying onm DB side without client filtering quite hard which could actually make your app slower.

But as others say it is upto your use case etc and it all depends on details you have not given us.

I may have left some details out but that's the basics, hope it helps

Edit: You can read about Mongo's schema performance and stuff here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design

Answer (score 0):

If you concern is performance, then you should consider using [automated sharding](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction) with mongodb mongodb.  Unless the data is usually queried separately, splitting your data into multiple collections will make your application logic more complex, without the benefit of sharding feature provided by mongodb.